# Ubuntu on a windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: intel, tablet

I would like to ask if i could run the normal pc ubuntu version on one of the new windows 8.1 tablets with the intel atom z3770 or z3740?

It is possible?

Would be nice, because the hardware and the price sounds great but windows 8 isn't it for me because i'm a open-source and diy guy.

Or

Are they cheapie convertible? I searched the web but didn't found a list with products working with ubuntu.

Comment: Intel makes x86 and x64 processors exclusively, so this should be possible. However, you will have trouble getting into the BIOS to change the boot options, and your tablet may not have a USB or CD drive in the first place, in which case it may be impossible to install Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: The main problem is listed here: http://askubuntu.com/q/392719/8500

Comment: Most windows 8.1 tablet have usb so you can use it to install it and ubuntu 16.04 supports UEFI well (I think). Just keep in mind that tablets have really weird hardware chips with no opensource drivers in most cases. Common problems are camera (or camera switcher if it has 2 cams), bluetooth, wifi, sound. So, better take a live ubuntu usb and go to a store and ask them to try it to see if it works (don't install just choose try, if they let you :P  ).

Comment: Yep, wirelles is not guaranteed to work, I was planning to use an USB ethernet adapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support)

Answer (score 0):

In window 8.1 you can go at PC setting and make the tablet boot from USB then you need a mini USB to USB female adapter plug it in with a USB stick with buntu with a ueif boat able. I plan to do same I have a proscan model it only has 1gb of ram so think to dual boot lubuntu on it on a 64 GB SD card half for Ubuntu and half for windows only questions I have is boatloader will grub work

Comment: If I had a 2gb model I'd just leave it alone but need something else that can use 1gb of ram because w8.1 suck at one GB think it idles at 60% used so there's like 300 mb left

Answer (score 0):

If you have 8.1 there could be hope in my experience. I was able to boot into Grub with a **32 bit Bootia** file set into **/BOOT/EFI** inside an USB drive.

I didn't have knwoledge about how to boot manually so no Ubuntu for me in that Tablet.

You will need to put the file found below into your EFI/Boot directory: https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/raw/master/boot/bootia32.efi

Then **boot manually** from the Grub command prompt.