# Installing Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) on a Windows 8 bay trail atom tablet

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, uefi, 32-bit

"How can I install 64-bit Ubuntu on my 32-bit UEFI Bay Trail atom tablet?"

To those of you who marked this question as off-topic, because it is related to a no longer supported version of Ubuntu... This was posted in May, before Ubuntu 14.10 had reached it's End of Life. reference below:

> Ubuntu announced its 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) release almost 9 months
>   ago, on October 23, 2014. As a non-LTS release, 14.10 has a 9-month
>   month support cycle and, as such, the support period is now nearing
>   its end and Ubuntu 14.10 will reach end of life on Thursday, July 23rd

This post [can be found here](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2015/07/03/ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-23-2015/)

Comment: Maintaining a current status post on Ubuntu/bay trail compatibility here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2294927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: As of right now, Ubuntu 15.04 will BOOT on a bay trail tablet, but it will not install correctly.

My guide is based mostly on [this one](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/02/04/installing-ubuntu-on-baytrail-tablets-version-2), but with minor adjustments, and easier to follow instructions. This guide is tested and working on the Winbook Tw100 Windows 8 tablet (by [Microcenter](http://microcenter.com)).

You may require:

1. USB OTG (on the go) cable, for connecting the USB drive/keyboard/mouse
2. A 4GB or more USB flash drive
3. Any downloads mentioned below
4. You will need to disable Secure Boot and change the boot order in your tablet's BIOS settings

Problem 1: Booting a 64-bit OS with a 32-bit UEFI BIOS on a 64-bit CPU (it's like a jigsaw puzzle)

1. Download the latest [Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) ISO file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/)
2. Download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
3. Use Universal USB Installer to create a bootable Ubuntu 14.10 USB drive
4. Download this [bootia32.efi](https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/raw/master/boot/bootia32.efi) file from GitHub
5. Place the bootia32.efi file you just downloaded into the `EFI/BOOT/` folder of the bootable Ubuntu 14.10 USB drive you just created
6. Download these two .deb files, and place at the ROOT of the USB drive
   NOTE: due to broken links, files have been moved to Google Drive for permanent storage.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPvhHHEJKxNTzZqX0VBdFNfZ2M/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-BQVRZayI7OSvEszaK7Dtlg

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPvhHHEJKxNY25ZdW5KcEhLeG8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Hrq8K6bMvbFoEovBO7brnA

7. Connect the USB drive to your tablet and power it on

You should be presented with a screen like this, choose "Try Ubuntu without installing"
[image]

Problem 2: Installing, and making the installation stick!

1. After Ubuntu has finished booting, manually partition your tablet's internal storage

1.5.  If you want to Dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 8, you'll have to do all your partitioning using Windows disk management
2.  After you have finished manually partitioning your tablet's internal storage, install Ubuntu like normal
3.  When the installation has finished, leave the USB drive connected to your tablet, and restart
4.  When you are presented with the GRUB screen again, hit the "C" key, and enter these lines of code...

you might need to change the "(hd0,gpt5)" and "/dev/mmcblk0p3" sections of code to suit your specific needs

> linux (hd0,gpt5)/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic root=/dev/mmcblk0p3

> initrd (hd0,gpt5)/boot/initrd-3.16.0-23-generic

Now enter the "boot" command. If you were successful, you should not have received any error messages, and booted into your freshly installed Ubuntu 14.10 installation. If you receive any error messages, try the last two steps again.

5. Open a terminal, and enter "sudo apt-get remove grub-efi-amd64"
6. after that has finished, open the USB drive, and install these two .deb packages in the order that they are listed
7. grub-efi-ia32-bin_2.02~beta2-15_amd64.deb
8. grub-efi-ia32_2.02~beta2-15_amd64.deb
9. Open a terminal, and type "sudo update-grub"
10. Restart

And you're done!!! If you followed these steps very carefully, and to the letter, then you have a (not-so) fully functioning 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10 (and possibly Windows 8 dual-boot) bay trail tablet.

What doesn't work (this is a list for the Tw100, your tablet may be different)

1. Sound
2. Touchscreen
3. Battery (ACPI)
4. Accelerometer (tilting, screen rotation)

Check out [this guide](http://www.mctsol.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=1077&start=50#p3953) I did on how to boot Ubuntu 15.04 on bay trail tablets.

Comment: Tested the latest (wily-desktop-amd64.iso) 15.10 image on the same hardware, no apparent progress has been made concerning the compatibility issues that Ubuntu has with Bay Trail hardware. Will update within the next couple weeks of daily builds.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a Xubuntu based distro with a patched kernel integrating Realtek 8723BS WiFi card drivers, and both 32 and 64 bits EFI enabled, among other things. 
[XJUbunTAB](http://xjubuntab.xjesus.net)

Hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Use Fedora 34, it has a 32bit efi loader (as ParrotOS).
If you cannot boot it after install, reboot the live usb and:

```
sudo su
mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt
cd /mnt/EFI
mkdir -p Microsoft/Boot
cp fedora/grubia32.efi Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

If you have issues with sound, forget about all these UCM articles which refer to very old kernel. Now drivers are included and ready, but the chipset needs a quirk:
see [this article on how to add the quirk](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1896924) and [this one where you will find the correct quirk value](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211485)

Answer (score -1):

You should install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, which will install the required 32-bit EFI without additional work. However, Canonical does not currently provide the correct install media, so you will have to create it yourself. Instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/715843/463546

As of Ubuntu 15.10 and kernel 4.4.0rc7, a lot of things still do not work. However, a certain [group of people](https://plus.google.com/communities/117853703024346186936) are trying valiantly to get Ubuntu to work on various flavors of the ASUS T100. In particular, [Kirill Belyaev](https://plus.google.com/102558053651783798692) posts kernels and firmwares that get a lot of things to work. Although the hardware in each Bay Trail computer is frustratingly varied, it may help with your device as well.