# Ubuntu on 32-bit UEFI (only) based tablet pc

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, uefi, 32-bit

I've created a `bootable USB` of `Ubuntu 16.04` `64-bit` with Rufus, setting the drive to be a `GPT` for `UEFI`. Then I booted my tablet PC and I ran the `UEFI BIOS`, from which I turned secure boot off. I then restarted and went again on the `BIOS` to boot from my key, but all I got was a black screen that lasted few seconds and then it brought me back to the `BIOS`.

I read about a `bootia32.efi` file and other procedures that can be followed, but I didn't find a good explanation of what I need to get done.

My tablet PC runs an `Intel Core Atom Z3735F` and has `2 GB` of `RAM`.

If you have the answer please let me know.

Comment: [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/q/392719/253474), [Installing Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) on a Windows 8 bay trail atom tablet](https://askubuntu.com/q/619872/253474), [How can I install 64-bit Ubuntu 15.10 on my UEFI-IA32 Bay Trail tablet?](https://askubuntu.com/q/727664/253474)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So far you're doing everything right, you just need to modify the USB so that it will boot on a 32-bit UEFI only system.

While Windows is running or on another machine, insert the USB and find a directory called `/EFI/BOOT`. This needs to contain a `bootia32.efi` file (even if there is one there already it might not be one that works - last time I found one but had to replace it)

[click here to download a `bootia32.efi` file that worked for me recently](https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi/raw/master/bootia32.efi).

Drop this file into the right place (remember all the file and directory names are case sensitive) and your USB should boot, given appropriate UEFI settings (secure boot off, USB first or selected in boot menu)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! How do I commend your answer?

Comment: Awesome! By accepting it, which you did, thank you :-)

Comment: For the search engines, I'd like to add that his FINALLY got me to boot the Xubuntu linux version on my chinese PIPO X3 all in one pos terminal!
Thank you!

Comment: This file still works with Ubuntu 20.04 when written using Rufus in GPT mode.

Comment: Does anyone know how to add ``bootia32.efi`` to ``/EFI/BOOT`` from within Linux ?

Comment: @breversa, I extracted the official Ubuntu iso to a local directory, then copied `bootia32.efi` to the `/EFI/BOOT` folder, then ran `mkisofs` to create a new `.iso` image and booted successfully from that.  Example using RHEL https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1422213