# Installing Ubuntu OS

Tags: software-installation

I'm currently running Windows 7 as operating system. I want to remove Windows 7 completely and install Ubuntu.

How do I install it and is there any issue over installing Ubuntu after removing Windows 7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove win 8, install ubuntu 16.04 64 bit on a laptop with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/776268/remove-win-8-install-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit-on-a-laptop-with-uefi)

Comment: Should be easy - just download Ubuntu, write the ISO to a USB flash drive or DVD, reboot with the flash drive / dvd in, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove Windows 7. During the installation you will be prompted, if you want to remove it.

Simply download the iso of Ubuntu (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 desktop from here http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/). Then you can burn it to DVD or make liveUSB (How to create liveUSB on WINDOWS http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Then just restart your computer and boot form DVD/USB.
You will be prompted if you want to install Ubuntu alongside your current OS, or to erase whole disk and install Ubuntu. You want the second opinion. *Warning, this will delete every single file from your Windows installation*.

Then just follow the on-screen instruction to finish the installation process.

Enjoy Ubuntu and welcome to the community! :)