# I can't boot my ubuntu usb on my laptop

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8, live-usb, laptop

I have an Asus laptop with Windows 8.1 installed.

I created a bootable Ubuntu stick, deactivated secure boot and fast boot, created a booting destination of the USB port, and chose to boot from there but it just keeps opening Windows. What else should I try? Thanks!

Comment: if it's a laptop that uses 32-bit UEFI you will need to edit your USB [see here](http://askubuntu.com/a/775507/527764)

Comment: My laptop is a 64 bit laptop. I guess it's a different procedure right? Plus it opens windows not like the other user, which sent him back to bios.

Comment: You can leave both secure boot and fast boot on as long as your USB stick was created EFI. The easiest way to boot is to hold CTRL while Power->Restart from within W8.1 and selecting the USB as your boot option. [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) makes bootable EFI easy.. assuming you are using a later Ubuntu LTS with EFI keys.

Comment: nope, mine is a 64-bit laptop (ASUS X205TA) and I can only use 64-bit Linux images, but the only boot mode available is 32-bit UEFI. Strange but true.

Comment: My laptop is also asus( don't remember the model) . How can I see if the uefi is 32 or 64? ( sorry if my questions are too naive)

Comment: @Oxiden I just tested 16.04 as per instructions in my above comment and other than the change from CTRL to SHIFT all worked on my ASUS VivoPC. The USB was created from a 16.04 ISO using Rufus in UEFI & GPT mode.

Comment: I was using the previous edition of ubuntu. I downloaded the latest and every thing worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

In windows start menu go to Settings -> Power Options -> Change what the power buttons do -> scroll down to the Shutdown settings now turn fast boot OFF , this is similar to a hibernation, do a shutdown, power back on enter BIOS setup, check settings, save & exit, then be ready to hit whatever key brings up the boot menu, could be F12, F9, then you should see your USB stick, if not you may have to go back to the bios and set the boot to legacy mode.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not sure about the boot menu. I tried booting it from the menu which pops when you restart windows while pressing shift, it has a boot option, is that what you mean? I booted something called like flash drive and nothing. Then to be sure I created through the bios a booting destination ( f:\  ) but still it loads windows. I am not an expert so sorry if I misunderstand things.

Comment: Plus the legacy mode is alreadey enabled.