# Elimination of Win 10 to install Linux

Tags: boot

I  have a Lenovo IdeaPad 100s that  came  with  win 10 installed. That  os occupies the  majority  of  the ssd  drive. Constant persistant  ridiculous  harrassment  to  upgrade  win10 which  requires  8 gigs when there is  only  1.8 gigs  free space despite  no  significant  files has  led  me to  want to  eliminate  win10 in favour of  Linux. But despite  having a verified  usb iso  win10  seems  to  overide  any attempt at an external boot. I would like  someone  to point  me to a download os  wiper that is  simple to use.

Comment: Maybe you have to turn off secure boot (in a UEFI/BIOS menu) for the system to boot from USB. If that does not help, can you use another computer to test that your USB boot drive is good and can really boot a computer?

Comment: When your done with that GPart Live CD will wipe the drive.

Comment: You have one of the 32 bit UEFI, even though system is 64 bit. It was created as Linux did not have a 32 bitr UEFI and they wanted a Windows only system. But now there is 32 bit Linux UEFI boot - bootia32.efi which you can also download. https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support  LENOVO Ideapad 100 Laptop 16.04 Dual Boot 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336544
LENOVO Ideapad 100S Laptop  32 bit UEFI bootia32.efi
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350606 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc

Answer (score 0):

[You can use DBAN to clear a disc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.3.0/dban-2.3.0_i586.iso/download)

However, if you can't boot into the Ubuntu installer then you probably won't be able to boot into this either.

Have you tried [booting to a USB](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21756-boot-usb-drive-windows-10-pc.html) from the [Advanced Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html#option1)?

I've known people unable to USB boot otherwise to have success with that method.

In the same menu you might also be able to access the BIOS settings and disable secure boot which can also be preventing you from booting from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Found  the solution.  Actually  very simple  on  the  Lenovo Ideapad.
Use  Novo  button, select  recovery, opt  for external os input  from iso usb.
The  Linux  install overwrites the  win  partition.