# Install 64-bit Kubuntu on 32-bit UEFI system

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, kubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have 2-in-1 laptop with Windows (32 bit) and 32 bit UEFI, what doesn't allow me to boot in legacy mode. In that laptop there is Intel Atom x5-z8300 (64 bit) and 2 GB of ram. I want to install (maybe dual boot) Kubuntu there, but the 32 bit instalation doesn't allow to boot in "pure" UEFI and the 64 bit instalation can not be installed, because it can't be run. I looked for simple solution, but did not find any. What should I do? (Windows there are so slow, even writing this Q lagged (this was written on the laptop))

Comment: See if anything from https://askubuntu.com/a/715843/158442 helps (maybe adapted for 16.04, which shouldn't differ significantly)

Comment: Also similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a system very similar to your specifications.
So here is what you've to follow,

1. Make a Easy to boot drive......with agFM files for UEFI32
   booting, You can find out more about this on their website.
2. Download Kubuntu AMD64 and copy it over to the USB stick  (USB
   DRIVE/_ISO/Linux)
3. Download GRUB2WIN and install it to your EFI system partition
4. Boot into your Kubuntu using the Easy
   to boot drive you've created earlier
5. Install it along side windows (Dual boot)....The installation will fail, but reboot
6. Boot back to Windows and Create a UEFI entry using GRUB2WIN and
   you can do all kinds of customizations there
7. Boot back to Linux and wipe out the WINDOWS partition
8. Use Gparted live
   to merge the windows portion to the Linux partition
9. You can remove windows UEFI entry, set grub timeout to 0, and set
   Kubuntu to default in Step 6 (in GRUB2WIN)
10. You've successfully installed KUBUNTU on UEFI32

Links :

- This is a video to get some clear idea of GRUB2WIN
  https://youtu.be/fkY4n2W18Aw
- Here is GRUB2WIN
  https://techseedr.wixsite.com/website/post/grub2win-standalone-offline-installer

Notes :

Notes this is like a hack to install 64bit UBUNTU OS's on UEFI32
I'm not 100percent sure about this process
But I've installed UBUNTU 20.04 GNOME and UBUNTU 20.10 UNITY with this....So I am pretty sure that it is gonna work
So, ALL THE BEST and HAVE FUN [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFSEB.jpg)
This is my LAPTOP I installed Ubuntu Unity with this process

Comment: And how to reinstall Kubuntu or something else, once Windows is gone?

Comment: Pretty big bump (3 years), but I'm sure someone will find this workaround very useful :). That is – I started using Arch Linux since and solved the issue with [booting the ISO with](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting_64-bit_kernel_on_32-bit_UEFI) and [installing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#UEFI_systems) GRUB for 32-bit EFI. However, I think your answer solves the original question, so thanks.