# I don't see the /EFI/BOOT/ directory!

Tags: tablet

I have a windows tablet (mpman converter10) and it's only UEFI 32bit capable.
Then i've found a thread at AskUbuntu : [Ubuntu on 32-bit UEFI (only) based tablet pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc/775507#775507?newreg=8ed2b248b4f443b28b4344699a8e6708)

But i don't see the efi/boot/ directory.
Anybody please help!

PS : I couldn't reply on that thread cause i needed at least 50 reputation, and i don't have any of these.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to ask a new question ,and to reference a previous question as you have done.  Have you created a bootable USB for an Ubuntu Linux distro?  It's on such a USB that the /EFI/BOOT/ directory will be located.

Comment: It is probably/boot/efi

Comment: But i did search for it in my usb, but no luck. And in the /boot/ directory, there's only the grub folder. I've used this bootable usb creator : https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/