# Install Ubuntu Mate on HP Envy Tablet

Tags: boot, usb, hp, mate, tablet

I have an older HP Envy Tablet (32 bit Intel Atom Processor) with attachable keyboard & would like to install Mate using a USB. I have disabled the secure boot option in the BIOS & have tried to boot with a SanDisk USB drive that has been formatted to install Mate 18.04. Is it possible to install Mate on this device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu on 32-bit UEFI (only) based tablet pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc)

Comment: From what I've read on the links that were given on this thread, the issue involved installing 64 bit Ubuntu. I'm looking to install Ubuntu Mate (32 bit) on my HP Envy (a 32 bit Intel Atom Processor). I looked at the directory on the USB stick that has the Mate install but found no /efi/boot directory to place a bootia32.efi file. Should I find another version of Ubuntu instead of Mate?

Comment: @Phil Leslie: is your Atom Cherry Trail processor based device actually 32bit? or is the Windows version just 32 bit? either way checkout "Linuxium" or "Isorespin" for missing drivers. 18.04 has fixed most of these driver problems but is 64bit only, you can get Lubuntu 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible if you have satisfied minimum requirements:

- 750MHz CPU or better
- 512Mb RAM or more
- HD video card
- Keyboard, mouse, speakers, sound card

Don't forget to change boot priority in BIOS
What are you using to write image to USB stick?

Comment: I used the USB Image writer. I used the stick to install Mate on a PC. I just used the same stick to see if I can install it on the tablet.

Comment: And what was result of booting?  Long time ago I was booting Ubuntu on Samsung tablet. But I've used Unetbootin. You should understand that there is no guarantee at all that tablet will work properly.

Comment: I disabled the secure boot & moved the USB Hard Drive to the first in boot options. The result was a notice that it was unable to boot from the source. When reading through some of the other links, I looked for the EFI/Boot directory on the USB Install but I didn't find any EFI folder at all.

Comment: Maybe it's hidden folder? .Did you checked "Show hidden files and folders" ?

Comment: the only hidden file is .disk. There are no others.