# Ubuntu 32bit NTFS ISO Available, or, How to Convert to NTFS Using mkisofs?

Tags: usb, ntfs, iso, 32-bit, distro-recommendation

I'd like to install 32-bit Ubuntu (any flavor) on an old 2017ish Win8Pro Dell Latitude 10 ST2 tablet. Official online support docs say my device *can* boot to USB ISO, but that it only supports NTFS.

I believe most Linux ISO's today use the filesystem fat, vfat, fat32 etc inside there..

QUESTION-

Any way (if an ISO already using NTFS isn't available) to download say a FAT32 32bit ISO, unpack it using mount, then newly create (on an x86_amd64 PC) perhaps using mkisofs a 32bit NTFS ISO to then dd to USB stick?

Thanks very kindly.

Peter L

Video2Video Hostmaster, La Jolla San Diego, CA, USA

Comment: You are confused about formats. ISO images are not FAT or NTFS. What I guess you are referring is the *USB* format?

Comment: Also to create a bootable USB you don't need to unpack the ISO, USB creators handle ISO images directly.

Comment: [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [multiboot](http://multibootusb.org/) are some of the tools available to create a bootable USB.

Comment: UEFI only boots from FAT32. And many systems like yours (not sure about yours) are 32 bit UEFI boot, but 64 bit systems. You need to install 64 bit version, but add the 32 bit UEFI boot file which is not included by default. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc

Comment: Ubuntu does not come in 32bit, use Lubuntu instead. Rufus and YUMI will make NTFS UEFI USB installs. YUMI for UEFI is limited to FAT32.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts