# Screen is blanking randomly

Tags: live-usb, display

I have managed to boot ubuntu on my Intel Atom based tablet (Odys Wintab 10) with the guide provided here: [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support).
The touchscreen works quite well, but I soon noticed that there must be some bug with the display (-driver) because the screen is blanking randomly in unity aswell as in console mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1). I could get the screen back when moving with the mouse or pressing keys randomly on the keyboard.
What can be the problem?

Update:
It is interesting: When I connect hdmi the screen is black again, but the output on the connected screen is okay. The problem seems to be the driver having to cope with both the display and the hdmi output...

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install fglrx`

Comment: On a intel based tablet? That can't be the solution...

Comment: Nope , it fixed my issues . My system runs on intel.

Comment: Also intel graphics card?

Comment: I had the same issue as your , installing it fixed my problem . Try executing the command or search for something else.