# Install Ubuntu (Desktop or Touch) on Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2 (Windows or Android)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lenovo, tablet

I'm looking into possibly getting a Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2. This is a pure tablet device, that comes with either Windows or Android. It has an Intel cpu.

Was anybody able to install Ubuntu on either one of those 2 flavors? What was the experience like? I don't mind using Ubuntu Desktop or Touch (or Ubuntu Next).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to boot from USB Drive after disable secure boot in bios. i also was able to install kali and ubuntu after removing windows from the 1051f tablet. i removed the windows installation and recovery partition (after creating recovery usb drive).

Till now, bluetooth wont work. That means, you need a usb hub and keyboard+mouse. GPS wont work and auto-rotation for the display wont work.

Comment: The 1051f needs a 32-bit EFI bootloader, which Ubuntu doesn't provide in its image. Can you give instructions on setting it up?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up instructions for getting Ubuntu (Desktop) installed on the Windows version (1051F): https://askubuntu.com/a/715843/463546

However, the trouble is hardware support in the kernel. I couldn't get sound or suspend to work. People work on patching the kernel to support various things in various devices, but the SoCs used in these devices don't lend themselves to an easy one-kernel-fits-all solution. Perhaps sometime in the future it will all work out of the box, and it's possible patches already exist somewhere that will do their magic for the Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2 1051F.

Answer (score 0):

I use xubuntu 20.04 with small tweak, and know BKC800 keyboard work well:

1. Install xubuntu 20.04
2. Download file: BCM4324B3.hcd
3. Copy file to folder: /lib/firmware/brcm