# Problem in installing Ubuntu on Q584

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I'm using Q584(Fujitsu). Its CPU is Z3770 and it uses 32bit UEFI.

At first I tried install Ubuntu on my tablet, NO boot device is detected but I found out that 32 bit efi is need.

So I used 32bit efi and I saw GRUB succeccfully. But When I select "try Ubuntu without install", I could see no progress but just black screen. no changes and I should reboot manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give legacy mode a shot. Usually you would able to find these settings under one-time boot menu, based on the manual document I [found on Internet](http://solutions.us.fujitsu.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/Q584-UG_B5FK-2441-01ENZ0_en-us.pdf), you should able to enter the bios menu by pressing volume button during powering on.

After switch to legacy mode you will should boot with the same 32-bit live usb/cd you created before.

But if you still thinking to use uefi mode or not able to find legacy mode, see this answer about [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) first.

Comment: Unfortunately, bay trail devices don't have legacy mode. and if I had legacy problem, I even could not see grub menu :( But thank you for your answer!