# 32bit UEFI better support than a year ago?

Tags: uefi, 32-bit, tablet

I'm trying to install Ubuntu or any other Linux on my Bay Trail based tablet and  following [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) advice. Internal display is supported only if I add nomodeset to installation boot option and touch is also supported, however during installation following error message appears and installation is interrupted:
Installation Failed
The installer encountered an error copying files to hard disk:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sbattach'
This is often due...

Installation is therefore interrupted.
Any help would be appreciated. As I appear to be very close after 30+ attempts using different distros to install Linux on the tablet.
In the light of huge popularity of these Bay Trail based devices, better support for them would be logical.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Liva X (which uses Bay Trail).  I was following the same instructions, and got the same error.

To fix it, I booted to "Try Ubuntu without installing".  I pulled up the Terminal, and typed

> sudo apt-get install sbsigntool

Then I picked the "Install Ubuntu 15.10" icon on the screen.  The sbattach error is now gone.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - is everything working for you now (wifi, touchscreen, sound, power)?
I'm currently working with 32-bit installation of debian and manually compiling drivers for touch and wifi.
Had success already, but it turned out to be unstable - freezing after some time.
If succesfull, i'll post instructions.
I'd appreciate your response about what's working for you and what not.
If touch is working, what's your experience with sliding/gestures - are they similar as with android (sliding works) or are they just simple mouse replacement, double tap needed to activate something?

Comment: Upgraded kernel to 4.4 willy and no more freezes. Touch works (mouse emulation), Wifi works, suspend/hybernate doesn't work, but I can live with that.
What's your experience with ubuntu?