# How to freshly install Ubuntu via Terminal (from Live USB)

Tags: grub2, uefi, 15.10

I am trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 on my Asus X205 from a live USB. During the installation I get following error: "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot." After klicking "ok" a prompt tells me, that the installation crashed and then the installation stops.

I already had 3 tries and every time I have the same problem.

During my search I found following thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1509620

The person gets the same error and has solved the problem by installing with terminal. Unfortunately I cannot find a hint how to freshly install ubuntu via terminal.

Does anybody know how it works, which commands I need and if I can do it from a normal Live USB or if I need something special?

Comment: `man grub` ?  - he probably installed only `grub` from the command line (using the live CD/USB). The remainder was in place already.

Comment: So I install grub before I install Ubuntu? Because I cannot finish the installation after the error prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install grub manually as described in this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi My Laptop has already partitions etc as the installation went to the grub-installation point. But still I couldn't install grub-efi-amd64 or grub-efi.

I figured out that I need to install grub-efi-ia32 instead of -amd64. After installing grub-efi-ia32, I didn't know how to (re)install Ubuntu without deleting and reinstalling grub etc. I searched for solutions and learned that Ubuntu 15.10 comes with UEFI-support for the 32bit-Version (older Versions had only UEFI-support for 64bit and I installed it on the 32bit system with this instructions https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md).

So I followed this instructions [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) including this step [32bit UEFI better support than a year ago?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723697/32bit-uefi-better-support-than-a-year-ago) to make a bootable 32bit-Version USB and to install Ubuntu on the Asus X205.

The installation went fine. Now I am stuggling with LUKS encryption but that is another problem.