# How to disable Page Table Isolation to regain performance lost due to Intel CPU security hole patch?

Tags: security, intel, cpu, patch

Because of the current Intel CPU security hole issue, there is a patch expected which slows down the system performance.

How can I make sure that this patch will not be installed on my Ubuntu system?

Comment: You can increase your system performance even further by disabling various other security mechanisms. No, that's not a recommendation.

Comment: If performance matters to you, I recommend building the recent kernel release candidate yourself and testing the performance loss on your workload. You may well find the overhead is negligible or tolerable.

Comment: I can't overstate just how terrible of an idea this is.

Comment: I am going to dissent . Personally I would not advise disabling security features, but, for users who notice a performance hit disabling pti may be a reasonable option considering how difficult it may be to leverage an attack against this particular security hole and the value of the target computer / data. The question is how to disable this option not should I disable this option.

Comment: I agree, PTI is a security feature that can have a non-negligible cost. Its up to OP to decide if it is right for them and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Security issues are not always applicable to every situation. Meltdown is horrible if you are a VM provider. It is much less applicable on your not-public compute server.  The question is legitimate and ridiculing by suggesting turning everything off is uncalled for. Meltdown requires local access. In many situations, if the "bad guys" have local access, you've already lost. Just because the media screams, this is - by no means - even remotely the same as a RCE or any other remotely exploitable bug.

Comment: Many comments here discourage this practice based on the assumption that the requester sooner or later will fall victim of hackers. What if the requester is a researcher who wants to test these exploits on his own machine?

Answer (score 57):

The patch (aka "Page table isolation") will be part of a normal kernel update (which you'll get when you update your system). However, keeping the kernel up to date is highly recommended, as it also gets a lot of other security fixes. So I would *not* recommend just using an outdated kernel without the fix.

However, you can effectively disable the patch by adding `pti=off` ([kernel patch adding this option, with more info](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10107415/)) to your kernel command line ([howto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)). Note that doing this will result in a less secure system.

There's more info and performance tests with PTI enabled and disabled on the [PostgreSQL mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20180102222354.qikjmf7dvnjgbkxe@alap3.anarazel.de) - TLDR is that it has a between 10 and 30% performance impact (For ProstgreSQL, that is - other things [such as games](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=x86-PTI-Initial-Gaming-Tests) will probably see less of an impact).

Note that this will only affect Intel processors, as AMD [is apparently unaffected](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/12/27/2) ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/7nnivq/amd_processors_are_not_subject_to_the_types_of/)), so this will foreseeably be disabled by default on AMD.

Comment: "... this will foreseeable be disabled by default on AMD." Does that mean that there will be an extra kernel version for Ubuntu operating systems running on machines with an AMD CPU provided by Canonical ? :)

Comment: No, the kernel detects (on bootup) weather it's running on an AMD CPU, and disables the fix if it is. @cl-netbox

Comment: According to https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/04/intel_amd_arm_cpu_vulnerability/ AMD chips are affected by at least one variety of Spectre attacks (branch target injection), so they'll be getting a probably-performance-affecting kernel update this week, too, even though they're not subject to Meltdown proper.

Comment: Apparently this feature is in x64 architecture, but not in i386/IA-32.because of this, the patch doesn't affect 32bit linux either(security/Kconfig requires X86_64 to enable PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION). that brings another question though. what about x64 machines with a 32bit linux installed, can these be affected? If so, what about old x64 machines which are limited by bios to only run 32bit instructions(like old atom-based netbooks)? are they sitting ducks?

Comment: Until I learned for certain there was a JavaScript based attack I was planning on using this.

Comment: What I've found at Aerospike ( high performance low latency database ) is that CPU use is not always an issue ( if you're running at 20% CPU and move up to 40% CPU you might not have a speed problem ), and second, Retpoline is really good. So say our users ( who care about latency ).

Finally, if you're already in a virtualized world, the risk of disabling Meltdown _in guests_ is priv escelation - a "Guest" account can do horrible things. But you've already closed off unpriv'd accounts, right?

Comment: @thePiGrepper there's no such thing as "x64 machines which are limited by bios to only run 32bit instructions". If a CPU can run x86_64 instructions, it's an x86_64 CPU. Those Atom machines are 64-bit ones, only the UEFI is limited to 32-bit, and [you can install 64-bit Linux on those](https://askubuntu.com/q/727664/253474)

Answer (score 35):

**Update:** The issue has been given a pair of monikers: [Meltdown and Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/). I've updated the answer with the new information.

It'll be a kernel patch initially. It'll show up as a higher version. It'll be installed because  you have `linux-image-generic` installed. That's what that package is for. So you could remove `linux-image-generic`. It's a horrible, **disastrous** idea, that'll expose you to [all sorts of nasties](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/) but you *could* do it. There **may** also be CPU microcode that follows in `linux-firmware` for an in-CPU fix. That's really on Intel.

**The method you follow to un-fix this is irrelevant.** You're asking to bypass something where you know neither the true impact of the bug, nor the performance cost of fixing it.

- The bug is nasty. The reported CVEs are cross process memory reading. Any process being able to read the memory of any other process. Input, passwords, the whole lot. This likely has implications on sandboxes too. It's very early days and I expect people to push this further, both in impact and access.
- The performance hit likely isn't as big as you're worried about. The numbers people are throwing around focus on the theoretical subsystem performance, or worst case. A poorly cached database is what's going to get hit hardest. Gaming, and day-to-day stuff likely isn't going to measurably change.

Even now we can see what the actual bug is, it's way too early to say what the impact is. While free read access to RAM is bad, there are worse things out there. I'd also test to see how much the fix actually impacts you (with the things you do).

Don't start pre-loading your GRUB config with flags, or removing Kernel meta packages just yet.

Comment: All you need to do is add `pti=off` to the kernel command line (in GRUB) to disable the patch.

Comment: @JonasCz that comment - if true, I don't know - sounds like it would be worth a separate answer, especially if you can back it up with a reference.

Comment: IMHO nopti is a better choice

Comment: @Panther If you read past the first main paragraph, you'll note my recommendation here is neither. KPTI is an important security feature for CPUs that don't handle this stuff themselves. Don't disable it until you know it's safe to do so (for you) and that having it actually negatively impacts you.

Comment: @Oli I agree with that advice and have given such myself elsewhere. With that said, the question is how to disable this new security feature if desired, and, IMO, nopti is the option to do so.

Comment: Yeah it has slowed some of my system activities down 99% when using virtual machines. Copying files from host to virtual machine used to take 2-3 seconds now it takes over a minute.

Answer (score 15):

Although I do not recommend this, it is possible to disable PTI

> with the **nopti** kernel command-line parameter

according to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=x86-PTI-EPYC-Linux-4.15-Test).

To do this, append `nopti` to the string next to the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and then running

```
sudo update-grub
```

followed by a restart.

More about kernel boot parameters to disable performance-relevant security features, see: [Spectre&Meltdown MitigationControls in Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls)

Comment: What's the difference between kernel boot params *nopti* and *pti=off*?

Comment: @niutech there is no difference, for proof you can look [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10107415/)

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls describes "nopti" and others..

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to the end of your kernel argument in grub:-

> spectre_v2=off nopti pti=off

Kernel parameters are described at: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls

Comment: The linked documentation says nopti and pti=off are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way: uncheck in kernel configuration

***->Security options***

***[ ] Remove the kernel mapping in user mode***

then compile the new kernel

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/792052)

Comment: Sadly J. Starnes is right. You don't compile your own kernel anymore except as an extreme last resort.

Comment: That is a rather trivial change to the kernel options, but, IMO `nopti` is probably a better / easier choice fo rmost.