# What have I to do with Spectre and Meltdown?

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04-64 bits. Due to the last news about these problems, please can you tell me if I have to install some patches and in that case what have I to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is an official [post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown?_ga=2.169669540.409936764.1515239575-605663649.1515239575) and have a look at  https://askubuntu.com/questions/992137/how-to-check-that-kpti-is-enabled-on-my-ubuntu

Comment: Just wait for the kernel patch scheduled for January 9 (or earlier). Eventually check for update daily to get it as early as possible.