# How to check Spectre patch by terminal on my Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, kernel, debian, patch

How can I check IBRS patch enables on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS by using command line

Comment: AFAICT the spectre-meltdown-checker script also checks for IBRS: https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/pull/112/files

Comment: Are there having any command to check Spectre patch? (Not KPTI patch)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/994193/158442