# Once processors are fixed for Meltdown and Spectre problems, what will it take to avoid software-induced performance hits?

Tags: performance, intel, cpu, patch

Software remediation of the Meltdown and Spectre problems slows performance. If and when non-problematic processor models come to market, or microcode updates fix installed processors, will kernels and applications need flags or recompilation to avoid the slowdown due to software-based remediation?

ref: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/05/spectre_flaws_explained/

Comment: if the processors are fixed, then software remediation would be unnecessary

Comment: This seems like an issue for the Ubuntu Technical Board to discuss...when it's no longer hypothetical. Not a support question.

Comment: I think we are putting the cart in front of the horse--Ubuntu hasn't releases a fix yet. Under kernel 4.14.12 (the Linux fix) I haven't seen performance impacted.

Comment: You should read the release notes on this. Basically you add `pti=off` or `nopti` , either one, to your (grub) boot options - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/991874/how-to-disable-page-table-isolation-to-regain-performance-lost-due-to-intel-cpu/991879#991879 for a discussion and this option. See also https://fedoramagazine.org/kpti-new-kernel-feature-mitigate-meltdown/

Comment: @Panther - nopti sets the worst case answer, and that is not so bad. I was asking if a future kernel will check for the problem itself and on its own, if it is safe, do nopti.

Comment: @ user535733 - Technical Board - Go for it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - Will wait.