# How to disable KPTI

Tags: kernel

Is there a way to disable KPTI (for meltdown mitigation) once the system is already up and running?

If the system is not yet booted, is it correct that passing kernel command line argument "nopti" will disable the page tables isolation?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/991874/how-to-disable-page-table-isolation-to-regain-performance-lost-due-to-intel-cpu

Comment: @pomsky reported link talks about second question, but it leaves me not satisfied. Some reports `nopti` some reports `pti=off`. I was looking for a definitive answer

Comment: @Jack - That is the definitive answer . Both options, nopti and pti=off, do the exact same thing, they only difference is syntax or the number of keys you type for the option you want. It is similar to long and short options, `ls -a` is the same output as `ls --all`

Comment: Sorry @Panther - pomsky Zanna WinEunuuchs2Unix N0rbert - but main question is not answered. Why have you mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: No, reboot is required

Comment: @Panther You may want to add this as a normal answer and let me accept it