# How to permanently disable attempts to install Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs updates?

Tags: drivers, updates, intel, firmware, microcode

I do not want to install Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs updates even by accident (I am more than willing to take the security risk). How to disable it being offered in Software Update and how to make sure I am not accidentally installing it?

Comment: If it's being offered in the updates, it's probably already installed. And you'd probably need https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/158442 instead to prevent further updates, or remove the package.

Comment: A better question is why do you want to do this and are you sure the problem is with the microcode ?

Comment: The fixes (which impact performance) for the recent Meltdown and Spectre attacks are in the kernel, so even if you don't update the microcode, you still get the performance penalty. Is this why you don't want to update ? If so, there's [a way to avoid the security fix, and thus the reduced performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991874/), although you still have a security risk if you do this.

Comment: To add to JonasCz comment, not everyone has a performance hit. Some have stability problems (random reboots) . In either case (performance hit or stability) you need to disable the patch rather than disable the microcode update.