# Ubuntu 18.04 works very slowly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. Before I had Linux Mint and everything has been nicely working. Whet I just installed 18.04 one, it was working pretty slowly, then it started working better little bit but still not enough. When I click on  "Show Applications" button at the left bottom corner it works extreme slowly. I have good hardware, I don't know why it works so. Maybe due to drivers? If so, how can I update all of them up to date (with terminal please)? I think it's due to problem about GPU or CPU drivers. When I had Mint it was working the same, but started working really good after installing CPU and GPU drivers.

8 GB RAM, Nvidia GTP 1050TI, I3 6100. I don't know what drivers, I just use standard Ubuntu "Software & Updates" for this.

Comment: What is your "good hardware"? And which drivers are you using?

Comment: @dadexix86 8 GB RAM, Nvidia GTP 1050TI, I3 6100. I don't know what drivers, I just use standard Ubuntu "Software & Updates" for this.

Comment: In software and updates there is a "driver" tab. What is selected there?

Comment: @dadexix86 https://imgur.com/jWtU6Ly

Comment: @dadexix86 also, "System Monitor" displays not bad statistic, https://imgur.com/csxL6O3

Comment: Looking a bit through Google it looks like the problems are the driverss from Nvidia, the 390 are apparently extremely bugging...

Comment: @dadexix86 I'll try to install another driver for GPU

Comment: Yes, try with the nouveau. If it does not solve, I suggest that you install the 16.04 again and wait for the proposed upgrade (usually around the release of the 18.04.1)

Comment: Did you tried installing the nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, it hasn't helped much. I noticed that the more I use Ubuntu the better it's getting.

Comment: May be Meltdown and Spectre fix that slowdowns your PC from 0 to 50%. Disabling it solves problem a bit. Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/991874/how-to-disable-page-table-isolation-to-regain-performance-lost-due-to-intel-cpu