# Hardware problems running Ubuntu on Lenovo 100S Ideapad

Tags: drivers, sound, lenovo, ideapad

I managed to install Ubuntu 15.10 on a new Lenovo 100S 11IBY Ideapad, a 32-bit cheap laptop that came with Windows 10 preinstalled and UEFI only boot system.

I followed [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) (response by Alexander Dubinsky). It worked flawlessly, but now I have three hardware problems I am not able to solve. I have searched tirelessly on Internet, but cannot find a solution.

The problems are:

1. No sound card detected
2. No wifi card detected (ethernet works fine though)
3. No power management capabilities (battery tools don't work, but the laptop gets charged without problems, there's just no monitoring)

I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest a possible solution to any or all of these issues, particularly the sound card and wifi.

Here's my lspci output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 203
    Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0f) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390c
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 201
    Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 248
    Memory at 90700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390c
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
```

Running `sudo aplay -l` results in `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcard found...`.

Running `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` shows no results.

I have tried the different recommendations found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting), But no success.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hadess has a mostly functional driver for this units WiFi. Google "Hadess driver sdio" or something. I have this exact same unit and I have the same sound problem I'm trying to figure out. Pulling out my hair. The battery monitoring is the last concern of mine right now. Please update with findings.

Comment: I have the same issues but on the ChromeOS version. Same access denied message, no sound at all