# Will we ever be able to install Ubuntu on a Win10 tablet like we can on Desktop?

Tags: grub2, uefi, windows-10, tablet

I've got a nice Win10 Tablet/Netbook, but I hate Win10.
I tried Installing Ubuntu casually on it, but It couldnt boot from the installation media.
I've found out that this has something to do with Windows tablets having a 32bit EFI, but Ubuntu and Grub only supporting either a Bios or a 64bit UEFI.
Also there would be driver problems and all if I managed to install it somehow.

Will I soon/ever be able to install Ubuntu on the Win10 Tablet without problems?

Comment: Yes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support