# how can i install ubuntu on my win10 tablet?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, live-usb

What I have tried:

1. I have tried using `dd` and Ubuntu `startup disk maker` to make a usb installer, but even I choose boot from usb, my computer still directly boot into win10. I don't know why.
2. I have also tried build a uefi bootable usb by the accepted answer (1st command line method) in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media), but it did not work.
3. I have also tried to build a uefi usb under win10 by following [this link](http://linux.about.com/od/howtos/ss/How-To-Create-A-UEFI-Bootable-Ubuntu-USB-Drive-Using-Windows.htm#step1), and I also disabled the secure boot option in bios, however system just won't boot from usb.
4. It seem that I have a 32bit UEFI(I am not sure though, the reasoning is that my processor is intel atom z3736, but my win10 is 32bit, **someone know how to check this explicitly** please tell me), and it is quite troublesome to deal with 32bit UEFI, according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support).

One thing to mention is that the iso is 16.04 LTS of LUbuntu...

[image]

Previously I have successful installed Ubuntu on my pc using the above two method, what's the difference and how to fix it?

the bios info:

[image]

Comment: i am sorry the photo.taken by phone is too large to upload, therefore i screenshot it, however screen shot pics can't rotate on my phone...

Comment: You will need a powered usb hub (must be powered)
plug a mouse, keyboard and usb stick containing the Ubuntu install media in to the hub and boot up.

Comment: Note that no hardware is Win10. Hardware can, however, run Win10.

Answer (score 0):

According to many articles, install ubuntu on a UEFI 32 bit system with 64bit cpu is troublesome, including the [official sites](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#General_principles), see the first item.

However, Debian is a savior and many people yet don't know this, including me. Salute to their developers! The latest Debian support 32bit & 64bit UEFI very well. You can see these two posts: [first by intel](http://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2015/08/11/update-on-ia32-uefi-and-linux-support/) and [second by Debian developer](https://blog.einval.com/2015/08/02#intel_justifies_mixed_efi).

To install it, you can download the latest iso image [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/multi-arch/), and make an usb disk following the [documentation-4.3.1](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en). Other method using `dd` or ubuntu startup disk creator should also work (I didn't try). After this, you need to choose to boot from usb.

According to [this post](https://blog.einval.com/2015/03/30#Jessie-EFI_6), you need to be careful with your downloads if you have a similar situation as mine:

> If you want to install a 64-bit system with the 32-bit UEFI support,
>   make sure you use the multi-arch amd64/i386 netinst or DVD. Otherwise,
>   any of the standard i386 images should work for a 32-bit only system.

*Please inform me if Ubuntu or other system has this support, I would like to try!*

disclaimer: I didn't test the drivers etc... Just able to boot into the usb and install the system..

Answer (score 0):

1. first build an start up usb disk using the [method described here](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md).
2. because we need internet access during the installation, we need to make our wireless driver to work. This is the most difficult part.

   - download the source from [this repo](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs)
   - using the method described [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819161/how-to-download-a-package-with-its-dependence-and-its-dependences-dependences-i) to download all the packages needed to install `build-essential` and `linux-headers-generic`
   - [build and install the driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1581711/comments/18) using:
     `cd rtl8723as
     make
     sudo make install
     sudo depmod -a
     sudo modprobe r8723bs`
3. Install the system with wifi connection.
4. The installation fails with the error: `grub-efi-ia32` package failed to install into /target/. Without the grub boot loader, the installed system will not boot. Damnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn!

Comment: I didn't succeed, ubuntu hide my emmc flash disk, I can't find it...