# Booting ubuntu 17.04 on 32bit tablet pc "Primux Wind"

Tags: uefi, 32-bit

I've been trying, with no success, to boot a Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 usb stick on this tablet:

https://store.primux.es/producto/convertible-primux-wind/20512

I've tried different ways, solutions found here, and in the end I managed to get to the GRUB menu, but when I select the "Try ubuntu" option the only thing I get is a black screen.

Does anyone has any idea of what I'm missing?

The guide I used to make this usb stick is this one:
[32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Disable secure-boot in the BIOS.