# Ubuntu Installer Won't Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I recently bought an Odys Winbook 13, which natively comes with Windows 10 preinstalled, and I intend to dualboot it with Ubuntu 17.10 via a bootable USB flash drive.

So far I've

- created a 15gb partition for Ubuntu.
- made a bootable USB flash drive via Rufus.
- disabled fast and secure boot.
- changed the boot order to first boot from my USB flash drive.

Everytime I try that though, nothing except an underscore in the top left corner appears.

I'm at a loss at what might be going wrong for the installer not to show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most commonly a corrupted or mis-created LiveUSB. Check the md5sums on the .iso, and re-download if they don't match. Re-create the LiveUSB, paying close attention to the Rufus options.

Comment: This says it is one of the crippled 32 bit UEFI with 64 bit cpu. You have to add the 32 bit UEFI boot files to Ubuntu to make it work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK6IUMaq2LI  Info on adding 32 bit UEFI boot files to Ubuntu ISO. https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support