# Installing other OS on Asus VivoTab TF810C

Tags: uefi, asus, 32-bit, tablet

I've followed many guides, gone through many trial and errors but I cannot seem to install Ubuntu, Debian or even Android on my Asus VivoBook TF810C.

I make it to the GRUB screen for these OSes but as soon as I select any option the screen goes black. I've tried nomodeset and forcing the resolution to 800x600 - still the black screen. I'm guessing it may be some driver issue or something fixable in the grub.cfg file - I'm hoping someone might now through experience.

Side note: I've tried different usb devices. I'm plugging them into the tablet through it's dock as the tablet does not have any USB ports. It does have a little adapter thingy for plugging usb directly into the tablet but that's at the office and I will only be able to get it tomorrow. However, I don't think the device is the problem since I get to the GRUB screen.

Anyway, thanks!

P.S. It came with Windows 8 which I upgraded to Windows 10 later on through bootable USB (there was some corruption so it was a fresh install)

Comment: You were not very specific on what you tried (Android & Debian are off-topic here), but did you try the correct architecture (x86/i686) of Ubuntu? and what release?  Maybe you tried x86_64 (64bit), or another incompatible architecture intended for different cpu to what you have?  When it boots you'll see error messages, by providing these we can know exactly what your issue is - but you've given us none of those messages.

Comment: Hi @guiverc. Apologies, I was vague yes. I tried Ubuntu 16.04 32bit and 64bit as per a guide I found somewhere(cannot remember where) but no dice. I also followed this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/715843) but no dice. However, following these guides never produced errors, just blank screens and possible freezes. I used Rufus to create all bootable USB's. Tried MBR and GPT partitions, tried ISO and DD mode still nothing

Comment: This is a Bay Trail tablet, right? I used to own one. There is an issue with the `i915` driver on Bay Trail tablets, especially as they often use DSI screens, like smartphones, which are unlike normal laptop screens. Can you search for people who have also had the same issue on Bay Trail tablets?

Answer (score 0):

That tablet comes with a 32-bit Intel Atom processor so you can not use 64-bit operating systems. Try a 32-bit version: [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads)  or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)

Comment: tried it with Rufus - didn't want to boot from usb. When selecting the USB as boot option in the 'limited' bios the screen "flashes" but does nothing else and I am still at the same screen. Then tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/715843) - booted from usb, got to GRUB, choose "try without install", prints hella errors (something about 'Got command interrupt ... even though no command operation was in progress SDHCI REGISTER DUMP') then shows Budgie logo and loading dots, loads, loads, loads then gives 'busybox v1.27.2 built-in shell (ash)' with no response from keyboard.

Comment: The tablet is connected to a dock from where USBs are plugged in and keyboard is functioning. Is this a problem? It has a little adapter for plugging USB directly into the tablet but it was in my laptop bag when it got stolen so I no longer have it. Do I loose dock functionality when the installation starts?

Comment: Should not be. If it is usb reconnecting it should reattach it if you did loose connectivity but it should not (usb is pretty generic)

Comment: If it is the dock loosing connectivity, is there someplace on the USB that I could put drivers to help the installation?

Comment: don't think so. usb drivers are universal so if you ever did connect the drivers are already there.

Comment: Bay/Cherry Trail tablets have UEFI only system firmware. They will not boot legacy BIOS images, which only the Ubuntu Mate 32-bit ISO includes.